# SQL - oracle - how to select specific department from join results

Tags: sql, oracle

Can you guys help me with this query? I want to modify it so that it only shows me those departments with at least 3 employees from this query (with the 78%), and not from (the original table of employees/department). Every time i try " having COUNT (department_ID) or @ the WHERE clause it gives me an error. Do i need to do a 2nd join? Thank you

```
select *
from
(
 SELECT b.employee_id, b.employee_name,b.salary, a.department_id, 
 NVL(a.department_name, 'N/A') as dept_name,
 max(b.salary) over (partition by a.department_id) as max_sal
FROM        department a, employee b
WHERE       a.department_id(+) = b.department_id
) z
WHERE salary > (max_sal*.78 )
```

Results:

EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_NAME            SALARY DEPARTMENT_ID DEPT_NAME               MAX_SAL

---

```
   7566 JONES                      3000            10 ACCOUNTING                 3000 
   7886 STEEL                      2500            10 ACCOUNTING                 3000 
   7944 LEE                        2400            20 RESEARCH                   3000 
   7999 WOLFE                      2500            20 RESEARCH                   3000 
   7610 WILSON                     3000            20 RESEARCH                   3000 
   7921 JACKSON                    2500            30 SALES                      3000 
   7900 FISHER                     3000            30 SALES                      3000 
   7788 SCOTT                      2500            40 IT                         2900 
   7910 SMITH                      2900            40 IT                         2900 
   7603 CLARK                      4000            50 EXECUTIVE                  5000 
   7596 JOST                       4500            50 EXECUTIVE                  5000 
   7839 KING                       5000            50 EXECUTIVE                  5000 
   8000 BREWSTER                   2500               N/A                        2500
```

13 rows selected

```
         This are RESULTS I need to get:
```

EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_NAME            SALARY DEPARTMENT_ID DEPT_NAME               MAX_SAL

---

```
   7944 LEE                        2400            20 RESEARCH                   3000 
   7999 WOLFE                      2500            20 RESEARCH                   3000 
   7610 WILSON                     3000            20 RESEARCH                   3000 
   7603 CLARK                      4000            50 EXECUTIVE                  5000 
   7596 JOST                       4500            50 EXECUTIVE                  5000 
   7839 KING                       5000            50 EXECUTIVE                  5000
```

6 rows selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the calculation using an analytic function in another subquery:

```
select de.*
from (select de.*, count(*) over (partition by department_id) as cnt
      from (SELECT e.employee_id, e.employee_name, d.salary, d.department_id, 
                   NVL(d.department_name, 'N/A') as dept_name,
                   max(e.salary) over (partition by d.department_id) as max_sal
            FROM department d JOIN
                 employee e
                 ON d.department_id = e.department_id
           ) de
      where salary > max_sal*.78
     ) de
where cnt >= 3;
```

The outer join doesn't seem necessary so I replaced it with an inner join and modern `join` syntax.  I also changed the table aliases to be abbreviations for the tables.  It makes the code easier to read.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see that using the over partition twice allows you to keep the count which was what kept me from getting answers thank you again...and happy night!